# Empty string + variable: why?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

The following is a line from `Backbone.js`:

```
return this._escapedAttributes[attr] = escapeHTML(val == null ? '' : '' + val);
```

What is the point of `''` in `'' + val`? Wouldn't `+val` suffice?

Comment: It's making sure it's a string value, and escaping it. "+ val" wouldn't make any sense if `val` isn't numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'' + val` concats `val` to an empty string, which results in `val` being converted to a string. `+val` converts `val` to a number instead.